# How do I query on new Rows of sql server table to update the results from the entire table

Tags: python, sql-server

```
Serial     Price     ProductIdentifier     ProductOrder
1          2.2       284                   1
2          2.3       302                   1
3          6.3       506                   1
4          3.2       284                   2
5          3.3       284                   3
6          2.7       302                   2
```

I have this sql server table which gets rows inserted in real time using a system. What I need to fetch is Price of a specific product(using Productidentifier) having the maximum ProductOrder.

I am achieving this using this query:

```
With CTE AS(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductIdentifier Order by ProductOrder DESC) rn
from tablename
)
select * from CTE where rn =1
```

The above query will work on the entire dataset, which becomes huge at some point and takes time. So, when new records come every second, how do I make sure to update my results with the new rows received without querying the entire dataset again.

If not in sql server, Can I use a python script to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can do that is to have a not of the data range you have used for the first query. If serial number is just increasing +1 for every new row inserted, your query should return both the `price` you are after and the `max(Serial)` so next time you query that dataset you can use a filter to say:

`WHERE [Serial] > @Max_Serial_From_Your_Last_Query`

Comment: But if I do that, it will not update the results, rather find the results from the new rows only. Right?

Comment: If you save both values `@Max_Serial` and the `@Price` you will be able to compare them, if the one form new set is bigger then you would return just that new one, if not then the old one. You just need to have a separate table to hold these calculations.